# Selenium 1 vs 2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am starting up a test suite for an internal JavaScript UI library for the place I work.

I have written about 10 Selenium 1 test cases or so in Python, for exploratory purposes, and so far it's gone well. I wrote the tests in Python and am using RC to run the tests in IE7,8,FF and Safari on the Mac so far so good.

I know Selenium2 is in alpha but read somewhere that it's production ready, whatever that means.

1) Since I am just starting out writing this suite, should I be using the webdriver API and Sel2, or is that not ready for prime time?
2) Can I use Sel2 with RC yet? It's unclear to me from Selenium's website if that is possible.

3) Anyone have experience with the Python driver for selenium 2? Or should I just write tests in Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am a Selenium Committer

I would say write your tests in Selenium 2 where possible as the bits that are complete are ready for use and work well.

There are bits that have not been fully implemented yet like how to handle alerts and a few others but the current API is stable, what it does in the background is changing but that shouldn't affect your tests unless we introduce a bug.

Comment: How about Java vs. Python and use with RC/Grid?

Comment: I personally think Java is the way to go (as of Feb 2013) using straight JUnit and a build system that can parallelize like Maven, Ant, or Gradle.  Also, even when running a local browser, I ALWAYS use the RemoteWebDriver JSON grid server.  It's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium 2 with RC.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.0a5.jar

I would use the Java API if possible.  Since the other APIs are ports and are not as up to date.